# TOAD elapsed time for the complete data set

Tags: oracle, toad

Toad by default gives only 500 rows. I have a query returning 100,000 rows. How can I determine the elapsed time for the query. When I do `ctrl+end` to fetch all records it still displays the time taken to fetch first 500 rows only.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to run

```
select * from your_table order by 1;
```

as it requires Oracle to fetch all data in order to be able to sort them. Though, you'll get some overhead (because of sorting, of course), but it will still be way faster than `CTRL + END` option.